# Adding HTTPS effectively in PHP website

Tags: php

I'm trying to roll out HTTPS on a small website with minimal changes, I am adding code at the top of the pages I want protected...

```
<?php
$securepage ="1";

if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on') {
    // we are on a secure page.
    if (!$securepage) {
      // but we shouldn't be!
      $url='http://www.mywebsite.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      header('location: '.$url);
      exit;
    }
  } else {
    // we aren't on a secure page.
    if ($securepage) {
      // but we should be!
      $url='https://www.mywebsite.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      header('location: '.$url);
      exit;
    }
  }
?>
```

The pages I don't want protected I remove the following...

```
$securepage ="1";
```

but when I try loading the page I get an error saying the page was redirected too many times.

Anyone have any pointers as to what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Try http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/ to check the `header()`s are working

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of developing an app, with the same requirement.  Some pages needs to be viewed over SSL (https) and others do not.

For pages that need to be viewed over SSL, I use

```
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]==80){ header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); exit(); }
```

For those that do not, i.e. can be viewed over http, use

```
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]!=80){ header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); exit(); }
```

if your page is within a directory on your host, then this may help too

```
"location:http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])";
```

Hope this helps...